# Angular - looking for a way to inject a component into another

Tags: angular

I have created a model box.  Injecting the header via innerHTML is easy where the header is small.  But I have multiple bodies that will be passed.
I am currently processing the bodies using ngif.  Is there a way I can inject the component that I wish to show? thanks in advance.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content modalBackGround">
            <div class="modal-header"`enter code here`>
                <div class="left col-11" [innerHTML]="header">
                </div>
                <div class="right col-1">
                    <button class="btnClose" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <abe-body-panel1 *ngIf="content === 'abe-body-panel1'"></abe-body-panel1>
                <abe-body-panel2 *ngIf="content === 'abe-body-panel2'"></abe-body-panel2>
                <abe-body-panel3 *ngIf="content === 'abe-body-panel3'"></abe-body-panel3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need Angular's [Dynamic component loading](https://angular.cn/guide/dynamic-component-loader).